# Table all row show the same datetime

Tags: php, datetime

I have a problem to show the datetime according the upload file datetime in the table. It always show the same current datetime in my table. My problem is how to show accroding my upload file datetime to show in the table?

Below is my coding:

```html
<?php
//$sql = "select * from promotion_list where id=" . $_GET['id'];
$sql_user = "SELECT *FROM upload_file_dms";

                $arr_user = db_conn_select($sql_user);
                foreach ($arr_user as $rs_user) {

                    $created_date = $rs_user['created'];

                }
$i = 1;
$files = scandir("uploads_media_file");
 $date = $files[$a];
for ($a = 2; $a < count($files); $a++)
{

    ?>

     <tr>
     <td> <?php echo $i++;?></td>
      <td>  <?php echo $files[$a]; ?></td>
      <td>  <?php echo $created_date; ?></td>
      <td><button  class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><a href="uploads_media_file/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" download="<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;">
            Download</a></button>&nbsp &nbsp
      <button  class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><a href="delete.php?name=uploads_media_file/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;">
            Delete
        </a></button></td>
          </tr>

    <?php
}?>
```

This is my database table info：
[Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTmoJ.png)

Below is my output info, it show me all same the current date time:
[Output3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NYtT.png)

Hope someone can guide me how to solve it. I want the `date create` column according match in the table data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your foreach loop where you define that variable $created_date is outside of the loop where you echo it. That means that php loops through the foreach and defines the variable over and over until the loop is over. Then the variable is just the last date (in this case your output)

Solution (untested):

```html
<?php
//$sql = "select * from promotion_list where id=" . $_GET['id'];
$sql_user = "SELECT *FROM upload_file_dms";

$arr_user = db_conn_select($sql_user);

$created_date = array();

foreach ($arr_user as $rs_user) {

    $counter = 0;
    $created_date[$counter] = $rs_user['created'];
    $counter++;

}
$i = 1;
$files = scandir("uploads_media_file");
$date = $files[$a];
for ($a = 2; $a < count($files); $a++) {

    ?>

    <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $i++; ?></td>
        <td>  <?php echo $files[$a]; ?></td>
        <td>  <?php echo $created_date[$a -2]; ?></td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><a href="uploads_media_file/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>"
                                                      download="<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;">
                    Download</a></button>
            &nbsp &nbsp
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><a
                        href="delete.php?name=uploads_media_file/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;">
                    Delete
                </a></button>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
} ?>
```

**Edit:**
I just coded this in notepad, maybe it doesn't work 100%, but it should at least give you an idea of how to solve it.

Comment: I have using your code paste to my code, but just show the first row only can see datetime

Comment: But did it display the correct datetime? If yes, I could try to fix that so you see every column

Comment: You can see this, output here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eAJWN3f8KHTFOHYEJ47W6gEJ1cT16U5l/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks janisch helping

Comment: Hi, sorry for not responding for an hour. Unfortunately I don't have much time to check your problem right now, I could analyse it better in a few hours. But for now, try the following:

Comment: Replace the following line:   <td>  <?php echo $created_date[$a -2]; ?></td>
with:    <td>  <?php echo $created_date[$a]; ?></td>

Comment: and if that doesn't work, try:    <td>  <?php echo $created_date[$a -3]; ?></td>

Comment: Ok. Later I go to try. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Janisch. My date also same cannot show well. The output herehttps://drive.google.com/file/d/1BfGmpg7a8yf7J7YoHRm8wK14rNdCfVmp/view?usp=sharing , have you time help to check for me

Comment: Hi, I'll check it out. Could you send a database export?

Comment: yeah, I just checked out your code again and I need a database export or at least a screenshot of how your database works to fix it.

Comment: Also, I need to know what your function "db_conn_select" does

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14hYW_mmySSSEW3BGHozBwKl2VZ-V6XT_/view?usp=sharing . This is my table.

Comment: and what does your db_conn_select function do? could you provide the code of it?

Comment: If without db_conn_select function, can you check it?

Comment: What do you mean? I just need to know what it does. I just need the code snippet of your function "db_conn_select". I guess you wrote it yourself in the same file or in another? I need that code

Comment: Ok, I wrote it another file.